# How to disable mouse click in wpf listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to disable the mouse click in listbox or any some of controls. only disable the click event handler and mouse cursor will be shown.How to make disable that?
Please tell me valuable suggestion.
if this is simple question to you, please forgive me.

Comment: Why do you want to disable it? Is it cause of the selection?

Comment: If you want to disable the styling of a selected item, you might want to use an `ItemsControl`. It does not  does not track selected items.

Comment: Another idea is to apply a style and set the `Focusable` property to `false`. This might be better, if you want to disable the selected style to other controls as you mentioned.

Comment: @ChristianMurschall Thanks for your replies.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom yes,it is cause of the listbox item selection.

Comment: Then I would do it like ChristianMurschall mentioned. Replace it with an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: WPF UIElement has  IsHitTestVisible property, set it to false and see.

Answer (score 1):

Set `IsHitTestVisible` to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

My question would be "Why do you want to do it? Perhaps there is another method to program what you want to achieve."

If you nevertheless want to stick with disabling mouse click event, I'd assign an empty event handler to the listbox and its items.

XAML:

```
<ListView MouseDown="emptyEventHandler" MouseDoubleClick="emptyEventHandler" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="emptyEventHandler" />
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="emptyEventHandler" /> 
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

and code (to actually catch the event and prevent it from bubbling up):

```
private void emptyEventHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

This way you can still react on the mouse click and double-click events in *Preview* event handlers. If you want to completely "hide" those events, then handle *PreviewMouseDown* and *PreviewMouseDoubleClick* events instead.